# maven build is failing due to dependency package does not exist while dependency package actually exists

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar

I have two spring-boot projects in Eclipse.

1. commons-lib
2. keygenerator-service

keygenerator-service has dependency on commons-lib so I have built commons-lib first and jar got created successfully in m2 folder. Then I have mentioned the dependency on keygenerator-service's pom.xml file like below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abz</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

jar file is present as C:\Users\snsur.m2\repository\com\abz\commons-lib\1.0.0\commons-lib-1.0.0.jar and looks good.

But now when I am trying to do maven build of keygenerator-service getting below errors:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Drive D/Projects/workspace-backend/workspace1/keygenerator-service/src/main/java/com/abz/keygenerator/core/KeyStore.java:[13,33] package com.abz.commons.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Drive D/Projects/workspace-backend/workspace1/keygenerator-service/src/main/java/com/abz/keygenerator/core/KeyStore.java:[14,33] package com.abz.commons.exception does not exist
```

I could see the package exists in the jar file as well.

```
C:\Users\snsur\Documents\Work\SWs\jdk-11.0.11\bin>jar tvf C:\Users\snsur\.m2\repository\com\abz\commons-lib\1.0.0\commons-lib-1.0.0.jar
0 Thu Jul 29 21:33:44 IST 2021 META-INF/
358 Thu Jul 29 21:33:44 IST 2021 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
.....
0 Thu Jul 29 21:33:46 IST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/abz/commons/exception/
0 Thu Jul 29 21:33:46 IST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/abz/commons/model/
INF/classes/com/abz/commons/exception/AlreadyExistsException.class
INF/classes/com/abz/commons/exception/InvalidDataException.class
```

I have checked many stackoverflow link for this type of issue but nothing works for me. I even deleted .m2 folder and freshly built the commons-lib project but still no luck.

**Please help me to successfully build keygenerator-service with commons-lib jar.**

Comment: This is a job for a multi module build...that means you have to move both projects under the umbrella of a parent and you can build them in one go (under the assumption you have defined the dependencies correct) and the order will be handled by Maven ... But of course if a jar is build as a spring boot maven plugin it is no longer able to be used as a usual dependency...that does not work.

Comment: Yes, as I have built the jar as spring boot maven plugin so it didn't work. So I have added some plugins in pom.xml of my commons-lib spring boot project which made it as library and now it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a runnable spring boot jar.

Making it runnable destroys its ability to be used as a dependency (notice the path prefixes)

Fix: only do this to the final jar you want to run.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion worked. I have added some plugins in pom.xml which made it as library.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the suggestion from Thorbjorn , I have resolved like this in commons-lib pom.xml

(For spring boot 2.x)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>repackage</id>
        <configuration>
          <classifier>exec</classifier>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Now it is working as dependency / library.